# Processing, bullet position for firing

Tags: java, processing

I am very new to Processing, and given myself the task of creating a defenders type game, however I can't figure out how to get the bullet to fire at the same position as the defender, I created a 'Defenders' class and a 'bullet' class and tried to use the variables that are in the defenders class in the bullet class however it is still not working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

//////bullet class variables

```
  int y = d1.y;
  int x = d1.x;
  int speedX = -1;
  int size = 10;
```

///moving the bullet

```
  void move()
  {
   x=x-speedX; 
  }
```

//////drawing the bullet

```
  void render()
  {
    fill(200,0,250);
    rect(x,y,size+15,size);

  }
```

/////getting the bullet to move in response to the mouse

```
  void keyPressed()
  {    
  d1.keyPressed();
  if(key == CODED)
  {
    if(keyCode == CONTROL)
    {
      render();
      move();
    }
  }
```

//////Defender class variables

```
  int y = 25;
  int x = 50;
  int deltaX = 4;
```

////drawing the defender

```
  void render()
  {
    fill (250, 0, 0);
    rect(x,y,25,50);
    triangle(75,y+15,75,y+35,90,y+25);
  }
```

//////moving the defender in response to the mouse

```
 void keyPressed()
{
  if(keyPressed == true)
  {
    if(keyCode == UP)
    {
      y=y-1;
    }
    if(keyCode==DOWN)
    {
      y=y+1;
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint in the fire method? There is no fire method. How many threads do you have?

Comment: yeah sure, 
   ArrayList<bullet> bullets;
void setup(){
 size(800,400);
  bullets = new ArrayList <bullet> ();
 
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   bullets.add(new bullet());
 }
 }
void draw ()
{
  a1.render();
  d1.render();    
  bullet b=bullets.get(0);  
  b.keyPressed();     
}

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/sedj601/DiverFx. Go check out the Diver class, FXMLDocumentController class, and the Harpoon class. This may help you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This should **not** be your entire project, but it should be enough code so we can copy and paste it and run it ourselves. For this question, having a circle that moves towards another circle would be enough.